# FastAPI form variable not sent to another endpoint

Tags: python, jinja2, fastapi

I have a simple HTML page with input field and button made in FastAPI via Jinja2 template
[image: input field, origin is placeholder]

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <form method="POST" action="/searchresultpage" class="form-inline" id="signup-form">

        <div class="form-group input-group-lg">
            <input type="text" name="origin" class="form-control input-lg" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                   placeholder="Origin">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

endpoint def

```
@app.get("/")
@app.get("/search")
def search(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("search.html", {"request": request, "message": "Search"})
```

I want input text to be sent to another endpoint as varialbe but whatever I input, I always get "origin" as variable.

```
@app.post("/searchresultpage")
def search_result_page(request: Request, text: str = Form("origin")):
    matched_movies = load_movies_from_db(text)
    matched_actors = load_actors_from_db(text)
    return templates.TemplateResponse("search_result_page.html", {"request": request,
                                                                  "text": text,
                                                                  "actors": matched_actors,
                                                                  "movies": matched_movies})
```

How can I get input text as variable to `def search_result_page` ?

Comment: need to be adjuested: `def search_result_page(request: Request, origin: str = Form("origin")):`

Comment: The argument to `Form` is the _default_ value, it's not the field name. The field name is given from the _name_ of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your endpoint expects a form field with the **name** "text", which you then set to a default **value** of 'origin'. Try this:

```py
def search_result_page(request: Request, origin: str = Form(...)):
   ...
```